# please provide sample app on proximity alerts in android

Tags: android, proximity

Hi friends  i am doing one app which requires to use ProximityIntent  for showing proximity alerts i was surfing from one day but i did'nt find any sample app which shows it. i found some links but they are complex please help to find out some useful links

the links i have seen which is complex and not clear is

http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/07/part-3-developing-proximity-alerts-for-mobile-applications-using-the-android-platform/

please help me...

Comment: i badly need u r help plz help me friends